# AppleScript: how to eject/unmount NAS?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to eject/unmount a mounted NAS.
It has been mounted with:

```
set serverName to "MyNAS"
tell application "Finder" to open location ("afp://" & theUser & ":" & thePass & "@" & serverName)
```

I tried:

```
tell application "Finder" to do shell script "diskutil umount \"" & serverName & "\"" --***
tell application "Finder" to eject serverName
```

But it returns a -10010 error: appleEvent can't handle objets of this class.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try dropping `diskutil` and just using `umount` maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use always the Finder?

`open location` and `do shell script` are part of `Standard Additions`, they are none of the Finder's business.

```
set serverName to "MyNAS"
open location ("afp://" & theUser & ":" & thePass & "@" & serverName)
```

and

```
do shell script "diskutil umount \"" & serverName & "\"" --***
```

The error occurs because you are trying to eject a literal string rather then the **`disk`**`serverName`

---

Usually you are mounting a disk of a server

```
open location ("afp://" & theUser & ":" & thePass & "@serverName.local/volumeName")
```

and you are ejecting the volume, not the server

```
tell application "Finder" to eject disk "volumeName"
```

Comment: I previously tried: do shell script "diskutil umount " & serverName with the same result. I didn't pass volumeName in the mounting process to choose manually which NAs' volume to mount. I would like to "eject" the server with AppleScript, like the little icon "eject" in the Finder's lateral bar do. Maybe it's not possible?